# serviceworkers focus tab: clients is empty on notificationclick

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

I have a common serviceworker escenario, where I want catch a notification click and focus the tab where the notification has come from. However, clients variable is always empty, its lenght is 0

```js
console.log("sw startup");
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log("SW installed");
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log("SW activated");
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (e) {
    // Android doesn't automatically close notifications on click 
    console.log(e);
    e.notification.close();
  
    // Focus tab if open
    e.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window'
    }).then(function (clientList) {
        console.log("clients:" + clientList.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; ++i) {
            var client = clientList[i];
            if (client.url === '/' && 'focus' in client) {
                return client.focus();
            }
        }

        if (clients.openWindow) {
            return clients.openWindow('/');
        }
    }));
    
});
```

And the registration is this one:

```js
 this.doNotify = function (notification) {      
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function (reg) {
               
                requestCreateNotification(notification, reg);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('sw reg error:' + err);
            });
        }
   ...
   }
```

chrome://serviceworker-internals/ output shows that registration and installation are fine. However, when a notification is pushed,  clientList is empty. I have tried removing the filter type:'window' but the result is still the same. As clients are empty, a new window is always opened. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the reason...what if I open another tab, or refresh the page, it detects the client. So I suppose we need to refresh the page so it starts detecting clients?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The suspicion in your own comment is correct. A page is controlled by a service worker *on navigation to an origin that the service worker is registered for*. So the original page load that actually initializes the service worker is not itself controlled. That's why the worker only finds your tab once you visit with a new tab or do a refresh.

However (as Jeff Posnick points out in the comments) you can get uncontrolled pages as follows: `ServiceWorkerClients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'})`.

Comment: Alternatively, [`ServiceWorkerClients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/matchAll) will give you back `Client` objects that correspond to pages that are not yet controlled. (Feel free to edit your answer to include that info if you'd like; I'm not going to take the liberty.)

Comment: Where is the "ServiceWorkerClients" object coming from in this example?

Answer (score 5):

Try making the service worker immediately claim the page.
E.g.:

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting()));

self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()));
```

For a more complex example, see https://serviceworke.rs/immediate-claim.html.

Comment: What's the point of using `waitUntil()` on `skipWaiting()` and `claim()` if both of those methods return "A Promise that resolves to undefined."

Comment: This is a case where you don't care about the value associated to a promise, but you just need to wait for the promise to be resolved.
For `skipWaiting` you don't really need it, as `skipWaiting` returns immediately and is not really an asynchronous operation.
`clients.claim` is an asynchronous operation, if you don't use `waitUntil`, the browser can kill the service worker while the operation is still in progress.