# How to pass data from service worker to Angular JS controller

Tags: angularjs, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I want to pass some data which I received through chrome push notification to my controller in angular js

my sw.js is

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {  
   //console.log('Received a push message', event.data.json());
   var obj = event.data.json();
   var title = obj.title;  
   var body = "Customer number : "+obj.payload.customer_number+" \nCustomer address : "+obj.payload.customer_address;  
   var icon = 'assets/images/favicon-192.png';  
   var tag = 'sfxorder';
   var sound = 'assets/audio/ping.mp3';
   event.waitUntil(  
      self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
        body: body,  
        icon: icon,  
        tag: tag,
        sound:sound ,
        vibrate: [300, 100, 400] 

        })  
      );  
  });
```

I am receiving the data in above method but How to pass this data to controller ?

Comment: you can add this code into the controller directly (replace `self` with `window`) and so you should be able to access the controller's variables (you may need to call `$apply` to sync with the Angular cycles).

Comment: I tried your solution but its not working...

Comment: @mallip did you get solution , can you share some code here? Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to immediately send a message to one or more client pages from a service worker, then using the [`Client.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client) method would be the best approach.

Here's an excerpt from [a full sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/index.html):

```
// From within your service worker, you can get a list of active clients
// and call postMessage() to communicate with any of the ones you want:
self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clients) {
  clients.forEach(function(client) {
    client.postMessage({foo: 'bar'});
  });
});


// From within your client pages, you can listen for messages via:
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // Do something with event.data
});
```

If you just want to save data that might be used later on by a client page, but you don't need to notify the client page immediately, the saving it to [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) would be the most appropriate approach.

Comment: I want to play the sound when push notification receives. Some how i need to call one method from my controller to play the sound when message receives.  I tried your solution it is working if multiple tabs open , if one tab is open its not working

Comment: Got it . its working thanks for you answer it drives me in right direction.  Thanks to  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100759/serviceworkers-focus-tab-clients-is-empty-on-notificationclick)