# Why message listener does not work at first page load?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

The problem that if I open an incognito window of chrome, 
the updateLocalId() does not run. So I guess I dont receive events from sw.

But if I reload the page, everything works fine.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
    .then((registration) => {
      console.info('[main] ServiceWorker registration successful: ', registration, ' ', '');
    }, (err) => {
      console.error('[main] ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });

  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', async function (event) {
    self.updateLocalId(event.data);
  });
}
```

From SW I send message in the next way:

```
function send_message_to_all_clients(msg) {
   self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
        clients.map(client => client.postMessage(msg))
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100759/serviceworkers-focus-tab-clients-is-empty-on-notificationclick)

"A page is controlled by a service worker on navigation to an origin that the service worker is registered for. So the original page load that actually initializes the service worker is not itself controlled"

Updated function of sending message from SW:

```
function send_message_to_all_clients(msg) {
   self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'}).then(clients => {
   console.log('[sync] clients', clients);
     clients.map(client => client.postMessage(msg))});
}
```